# How to get data from MySQL generated XML?

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, xml

I have an app to send data from iPhone to MySQL server and I got it with request from objective-c and php on server.

Now, I want to receive data from server by XML. I have created a php code to generate data from MySQL to XML. How can I code in objective-c to call this php code? The goal is using this XML to parse and display on iPhone (I have objective-c code to parse xml file from link on server).

Please help me if you know and used to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Web-servces` Like XML- RPC, SOAP ,REST

To connect to a mysql database, your best bet is to use JSON/SOAP/XML/PHP or some combo of the mentioned, to talk between your database and your app..

The reason database connection directly from the device is a bad idea, is that you have to enable global external access to it for it to work. You can keep your data safer by having scripts on your server do the communication to the database.

Comment: Thanks for this post so much. But I don't see clearly about how to get data from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to expose a service of some kind (a URL the iPhone app can call).

Your app can call this URL with NSURLConnection (or lots of others).

This will return you an NSData * object.

Your app will then need to parse this raw data into XML (or JSON or a few others).  You can use NSXMLParser (and lots of others) to do the parsing.

Then, you need to translate the XML into useful business objects.